# How to get selected elemnent from Observable async?

Tags: angular

I have observable data:

```
 public documents$: Observable<SubjectRequestDocument>;
```

That I iterate in template:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="documents$ | async as document">
    <app-checkbox (click)>="setSelected(document)"</app-checkbox>
</ng-container>
```

When user clicks `app-checkbox` I call:

```
setSelected(document) {
   document.selected = !document.selected;
}
```

So, how to get all selected documents from observable data after click:

```
getSelected() {
   // HERE?
}
```

Comment: Should I use `BehaviorSubject`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use tap operator to get all the document items somethink like this:

**component.ts**

```
documents$.pipe(tap(item=>{ this.selectedItem = item;}));
```

Then Inside getSelected method you can filter the selected item.

```
getSelected() {
   this.selectedItem.filter(item=>item.selected);
}
```

Comment: Does not work, it gives me undefined in `tap()`

Comment: Maybe it is because there is no `.subscribe();`?

Comment: since you using async pipe async pipe will internally subscribe so that is not a problem here are you getting any other error?

Comment: I have created small example check this:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-rrhxfp?file=src/app/app.component.ts